# The location of the Lightroom database for the Android version

Tags: lightroom, data-corruption, android

I am using the offline version of Lightroom under Android, the problem is that I do not know the location of the database storage and this has i can,t me to be able to transfer the previous database whenever I install the new version or if I need to install Lightroom on another device for any reason.  I am not and all the settings I have made on the photos will be lost.  Note: I am unable to use the online version and my question is about the offline version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the databases/settings of LR mobile Android are located in

```
Andorid/data/com.adobe.lrmobile/caruseldocuments/[randomlongnumberstring]/Profiles/Settings
```

Also in

```
Andorid/data/com.adobe.lrmobile/caruseldocuments/[randomlongnumber]/renditions
```

you can find some cache files.